# Laravel: Get instance of Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, illuminate-container

I'm looking to encapsulate functionality that can be integrated into both a Laravel 5.6 webapp and a PHP-based command-line application. The functionality involves database interactivity.

For the sake of modularity, I decided to implement this functionality as a [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) module. Within the module, a constructor accepts an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager`. [I believe this to be the appropriate way to use Eloquent outside of Laravel](https://github.com/laracasts/Eloquent-Outside-of-Laravel), and thus assumed it would serve as a satisfactory lowest common denominator among Laravel and the CLI-based application. (The module itself works great.)

I am now attempting to wrap this module within a Laravel [Service Provider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/providers), and am encountering a problem: Laravel seems to mask its underlying `Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager` resource behind a `DB` "[facade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/facades)", which implements only `static` methods.

Question: within Laravel, how can I access the underlying `Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager` instance?

I'll note that I've been programming for 15+ years, but am relatively new to Laravel. With that said, if my thinking here is fundamentally contrary to the "Laravel way", please let me know of other architectural options. Thanks.

Comment: were you able to find a answer for this?

Comment: @Yeak, I was not. I've since come to believe that what I wanted to do is simply not possible, and chose to refactor my application accordingly.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you look for but anyway I ended up having a similar situation and I wanted to access the capsule instance when I was creating an application using some of Laravel modules outside Laravel.  There is an option to set capsule as `$capsule->setAsGlobal();` which in turn makes capsule instance available globally. So inside controller you may refer to it as `global $capsule`.